# Re: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 32756 bytes for ChunkP

Tags: java

I have been working on java project functionality enhancements. After complete the project I can deploy this into production server. But I am getting this error in the log file while accessing the application in production. Am using tomcat 7, jdk 6update 16.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate. Out of swap space?

  Internal Error (allocation.cpp:117), pid=17388, tid=38580
 Error: ChunkPool::allocate

 JRE version: 6.0_22-b04
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp


Current thread (0x022eb000):  JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=38580, stack(0x4a950000,0x4a9a0000)]

Stack: [0x4a950000,0x4a9a0000],  sp=0x4a99f760,  free space=13d4a99f770k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1fd0f0]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa471c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x29b2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2bb3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x53881]
V  [jvm.dll+0x53b38]
V  [jvm.dll+0x5577c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x56626]
V  [jvm.dll+0x5686a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x28317]
V  [jvm.dll+0x283b8]
V  [jvm.dll+0x28524]
V  [jvm.dll+0x28634]
V  [jvm.dll+0x88399]
V  [jvm.dll+0x88edf]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e7004]
V  [jvm.dll+0x185f3c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1339a]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ed2]
```

Can anyone find where is the problem and help me how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 32756 bytes
```

That 32756 chunk was just the last straw; it's the OOM error that's your problem.

What are your JVM memory settings when you start up?

Attach [VisualVM 1.3.2](http://visualvm.java.net/relnotes.html) to the Tomcat process when it starts up.  You'll be able to see the entire generational memory layout, threads, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What are your current memory settings defined for tomcat server ?

Try setting CATALINA_OPTS in catalina.sh

export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"

Answer (score 0):

A brief bit of searching on google leads me to believe this is related to the JIT compiler.  How many services are running on your server?  Is it a 32 bit operating system?

Have a read through this link : http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2008/01/14/jvm_lies_the_outofmemory_myth.html

What are your Java VM startup arguments?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, usually with Tomcat (6), you don't get this hotspot error when you hit your Xmx memory ceiling. In my experience this happens when the JVM isn't able to allocate any more memory from the O/S even though it should be "allowed" to. Could it be possible that you just don't have enough free memory available to allocate to the JVM?

If that's not the case you'll want to inspect the memory at the time of the error. If you aren't able to attach a profiler in real time you can add the flags: `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and  `-XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/dumps` to your CATALINA_OPTS then when the system next throws an OOM, it will dump it's heap to the folder specified. You can then analyse that with http://visualvm.java.net/ or similar Java profiler.